# Какой алгоритм выбрать для стабилизации видео?

Tags: c#, java, c++, видео

Столкнулся с проблемой стабилизации видео изображения веб-камеры. Пишу на c#.
Кто подскажет какой лучше алгоритм использовать или библиотеку.
Можно даже на другом языке.
В какую сторону копать в крайнем случае.
Буду благодарен за любой совет.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, стабилизации, т.е. - избавление от "дрожания" камеры?

Comment: Да, именно от мелких колебаний(5% от разрешения)

Comment: Нашел статью про алгоритм стабилизации использующийся на Youtube http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/37041.pdf . Сам я в этом не разираюсь, если что.

Answer (score 1):

В общем самый простой вариант - opencv